# Golang pointer not updated when passed to method as nil

Tags: pointers, go, recursion

I'm trying to create a linear linked list in go with recursive functions but for some reason I am not getting the correct result.

When I add a number to the list I noticed that `L.head` is never updated after the return of the `recursiveAdd` method. Shouldn't it be updated given that it is a pointer?

Expected result after `list.Display()`: 
1
2
3

Actual result: empty string

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Node struct {
    num int
    next *Node
}

type List struct {
    head *Node
}

func (L *List) Add(n int) {
    L.recursiveAdd(L.head, n)
}

func recursiveAdd(node *Node, n int){
    if node == nil {
        node = &Node{n, nil}
        return
    }
    L.recursiveAdd(node.next, n)
}

func (L *List) Display() {
    recursiveDisplay(L.head)
}

func recursiveDisplay(n *Node){
    if n == nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(n.num)
    recursiveDisplay(n.next)
}

func main(){
    list := List{}

    list.Add(1)
    list.Add(2)
    list.Add(3)

    list.Display()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.Add` does not update `L.head`. You pass `L.head` to `recursiveAdd`, but what you're passing is a copy of `L.head`, which is nil, and when you assign a value to that you only update the copy of the pointer on stack, not `L.head`. You can do:

```
func (L *List) Add(n int) {
    l.head=L.recursiveAdd(L.head, n)
}

func (L *list) recursiveAdd(node *Node, n int) *Node{
    if node == nil {
        node = &Node{n, nil}
        return node
    }
    node.next=L.recursiveAdd(node.next,n)
    return node
}
```

Comment: That solution work perfectly but is it possible to do it without return the node? Can `L.head` be passed by refrence? I thought it was, given that it's a pointer.

Comment: You can pass `&L.head`, and set the head in the function using `*node=&Node{}`. It is a little harder to look at, but it will work. When you pass a pointer to a function, that function sets the value pointed to by that pointer. If you want to set `L.head` you have to send `&L.head`, not `L.head`.